# Get group key from bridge table

Tags: mysql, database-design, sql-match-all

I'm developing an ETL process, and need a bridge table for a one-to-many relationship between a fact table and a dimension table (MySQL database). There is a limited number of combinations (some thousands), so I want to re-use group keys from the bridge table to to limit the size.

Any group of dimensions belonging to a fact row will consist of a number of dimension keys (1 to around 15), assigned to a unique group key, as below:

```
group_key | dimension_key
-----------------------
1         | 1
1         | 3
1         | 4
2         | 1
2         | 2
2         | 3
3         | 1
3         | 4
```

How do I go about retrieving the unique group key for the dimensions 1,3,4 (ie. 1)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for a query that returns the groups such that *all* dimensions in a specific list are associated with the group.  That is, rows must exist mapping that group to each of the dimensions, and you want to know which groups satisfy this.

```
SELECT f1.group_key
FROM facts f1
JOIN facts f2 ON (f1.group_key = f2.group_key)
JOIN facts f2 ON (f1.group_key = f2.group_key)
WHERE f1.dimension_key = 1
  AND f2.dimension_key = 3
  AND f3.dimension_key = 4;
```

The other solution is to count the matching rows in the group:

```
SELECT f.group_key
FROM facts f
WHERE f.dimension_key IN (1,3,4)
GROUP BY f.group_key
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

But I find that usually `GROUP BY` is a performance killer particularly in MySQL.

Comment: Your first proposed solution is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is a bridge table that looks like this:

```
group_key | dimension_set
-----------------------
1         | (1, 3, 4)
2         | (1, 2, 3)
3         | (1, 4)
```

You have 2 options that I can see.

You can either pull the entire bridge table into a program, and programatically determine the group key from the dimension set.

Or you can encode the dimension key using a mathematical formula to come up with an integer than you can index.

Something like `a + (b * 32) + (c * 32 * 32) + ...`  Use the lowest power of 2 that encompasses the number of unique dimensions.